# SSIS - What is difference between Error and Truncation?

Tags: ssis

What is the difference between "Error" and "Truncation" in configuring error page of SSIS component? Especially, What type of different errors can come under "Error" that are different from truncation?

[image: error and truncation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncation is "What do I do if I try to insert a 250 character string into a `varchar(50)` field?" or "What do I do if the metadata says `DT_STR` with a length of 10, but the data source gives me something with a length of 20?"  Some imports are alright with data being truncated, so it's common to want to make truncations silently ignored.

Error is, "What do I do if I try to insert the string `'ABCXYZ'` into an integer field?" or, "What do I do if I try to insert the string `'2015-02-31'` into a date field?", or "What do I do if I try to insert `NULL` into a `NOT NULL` field."  Most often it's an error of datatype, but could include an error of constraint (uniqueness, foreign key, etc.).  It's also going to be anything that's not covered by truncation.   Most errors I've seen come from the destination rather than the source.  Source errors at the field level might happen with different encodings, especially unicode vs non-unicode.   When the source fails, it's usually not a failure of a single field but of an entire table, view, or query, however, because of the way SQL works, but it could be if your source is a flat file.  We had a vendor decide change the order of fields in their file, and SSIS didn't react well to that.

Answer (score 2):

Errors fall into one of two categories: errors or truncations.

- An **error** indicates an unequivocal failure, and generates a NULL result. Such errors can include data conversion errors or expression evaluation errors.

For example:

An attempt to convert a string that contains alphabetical characters to a number causes an error. Data conversions, expression evaluations, and assignments of expression results to variables, properties, and data columns may fail because of illegal casts and incompatible data types.

- A **truncation** is less serious than an error. A truncation generates results that might be usable or even desirable. You can elect to treat truncations as errors or as acceptable conditions.

For example:

If you are inserting a 15-character string into a column that is only one character wide, you can elect to truncate the string.

Answer (score 0):

"Error" means, "I can't do this"

"Truncation" means, "I can do this, but I'm going to have to cut the string short at a certain point."